# How to use rdrand with Ruby and openssl?

Tags: ruby, random, openssl

i have a fresh OpenSSL installation (1.1.0 compiled from source) in /opt/openssl, and a Ruby installation, also fresh compile (2.1.0dev from source) in /opt/ruby, compiled with --with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl (all on a current Debian). Openssl can see my computer's rdrand engine

```
$ openssl engine
(rdrand) Intel RDRAND engine
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
```

and Ruby can see openssl

```
$ ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(4)'
"Q\a\"%"
```

OpenSSL::Engine is there, and can load an engine, too:

```
$ ruby -ropenssl -e 'e=OpenSSL::Engine.by_id("openssl"); p e;'
#<OpenSSL::Engine id="openssl" name="Software engine support">
```

If i now try to use that setup to call the rdrand generator, i get the following:

```
$ ruby -ropenssl -e 'OpenSSL::Engine.by_id("rdrand"); p OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(4)'
-e:1:in `by_id': no such engine (OpenSSL::Engine::EngineError)
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Am i doing something stupid here? In General: how can i use OpenSSL in Ruby and require a particular openssl engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, you have to load all engines first:

```
$ ruby -ropenssl -e 'OpenSSL::Engine.load; e = OpenSSL::Engine.by_id("rdrand"); p e;'
#<OpenSSL::Engine id="rdrand" name="Intel RDRAND engine">
```

Embarassingly simple, actually.